# read child process's output while it is alive

Tags: c++, stdout, stdin, io-redirection, createprocess

I have created two pipes with

```
saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE; 
...
CreatePipe(&childStdOut_Rd, &childStdOut_Wr, &saAttr, 0);
CreatePipe(&childStdErr_Rd, &childStdErr_Wr, &saAttr, 0);
```

Then i have created child process with next STARTUPINFO:

```
                        STARTUPINFO si;
                        ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
                        si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
                        si.dwFlags     = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
                        si.wShowWindow = SW_MINIMIZE;
                        si.hStdError   = childStdErr_Wr;
                        si.hStdOutput  = childStdOut_Wr;
                        si.hStdInput   = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
                        si.dwFlags    |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
```

Then closed write handles in parent process:
                                CloseHandle(childStdErr_Wr);
                                CloseHandle(childStdOut_Wr);

I wait while child process finishes with

```
WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
```

As i read on MSDN i can read chil process's stdout with:

```
for (;;) 
{ 
    BOOL bSuccess = ReadFile(childStdOut_Rd, chBuf, bufsize, &dwRead, NULL);
    if(!bSuccess || dwRead == 0) break; 

    bSuccess = WriteFile(hParentStdOut, chBuf, dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
    if (!bSuccess) break; 
}
```

**Q:** But where i must put code to read child's output?

---

Why i can't read cout and printf with these pipes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this I guess..

**ChildProcess -- main.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>


int main()
{
    HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if (!hOut)
        return 0;

    DWORD WriteCount = 0;
    char Buffer[1024] = {0};

    strcat(&Buffer[0], "Hello? Momma?!");
    int Length = strlen(Buffer);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        if (!WriteFile(hOut, Buffer, Length, &WriteCount, 0))
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**ParentProcess -- main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

void RedirectIO(HANDLE &hRead, HANDLE &hWrite)
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES attr;
    ZeroMemory(&attr, sizeof(attr));
    attr.nLength = sizeof(attr);
    attr.bInheritHandle = true;

    CreatePipe(&hRead, &hWrite, &attr, 0);
    SetHandleInformation(hRead, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
}

bool CreateChild(std::string CommandLine, DWORD WaitTime, HANDLE hInRead, HANDLE hOutWrite)
{
    STARTUPINFO SI;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION PI;
    ZeroMemory(&SI, sizeof(SI));
    ZeroMemory(&PI, sizeof(PI));

    SI.cb = sizeof(SI);
    SI.hStdError = hOutWrite;
    SI.hStdInput = hInRead;
    SI.hStdOutput = hOutWrite;
    SI.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    bool success = CreateProcess(0, const_cast<char*>(CommandLine.c_str()), 0, 0, true, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NO_WINDOW, 0, 0, &SI,&PI);

    if (success)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(PI.hProcess, WaitTime);
        CloseHandle(PI.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(PI.hThread);
    }

    return success;
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE hRead = nullptr;
    HANDLE hWrite = nullptr;

    RedirectIO(hRead, hWrite);
    CreateChild("C:/Users/School/Desktop/ChildProcess/bin/Debug/ChildProcess.exe", INFINITE, nullptr, hWrite);

    DWORD ReadCount = 0;
    char Buffer[1024] = {0};

    std::string data = std::string();

    while(true)
    {
        if (!ReadFile(hRead, Buffer, sizeof(Buffer) / sizeof(char), &ReadCount, 0))
            break;

        if (!ReadCount) break;

        Buffer[ReadCount] = '\0';
        data.append(&Buffer[0], ReadCount);
        std::cout<<"Read From Child:\n\n"<<data<<"\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It should print `Hello? Momma?!`  10 times.. Another option is the place the reading right after the `WaitForSingleObject` so that you don't close the process immediately and you can keep communicating with it. Maybe even create a thread and read in that thread or have the thread spawn the process and read.. Up to you.